# MYSQL, Subquery Reference in Union

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is there any way to reference a subquery in a union?

I am trying to do something like the following, and would like to avoid a temporary table, but the subquery will be drawn from a much larger dataset so it makes sense to only do it once..

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ads WHERE state='FL' AND city='Maitland' AND page='home' ORDER BY RAND()) AS sq WHERE spot = 'full-banner' LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM sq WHERE spot = 'leaderboard' LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM sq WHERE spot = 'rectangle1' LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM sq WHERE spot = 'rectangle2' LIMIT 1
.... etc,,
```

It's a shame that DISTINCT can't be specified for a single column of a result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no way to do what you're trying to do without repeating the creation of the derived table.

If querying `ads` is really expensive then you should try adding an index like:

```
alter table ads add index (state, city, page, spot);
```

If after adding that index the query takes too much, then I'd recommend creating a table to store this data and then query that table for each spot.

Depending on your data, you could play around with `GROUP BY` to get similar results.

Comment: Because tbl is just a reference for the first subquery. Maybe the name is a bit confusing. The ads table is large but after the subquery it is only about 90 rows. I'll update the alias name to avoid confusion.

Comment: My initial tests show that the following is doing what I want!....

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ads WHERE state='FL' AND city='Maitland' ORDER BY RAND())sq GROUP BY sq.spot

... So GROUP BY only returns one result per clause? I was thinking it was similar to ORDER BY. Thanks